# how to cache STL geometry outside of STLLoader even listener

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying read and cache a geometry from STL file with Three.js STLLoader. I'm using event loop callback to get the data (similar to STLLoader example). I intend to store in in external variable "cgeom". However, it looks like the geometry is not available outside of the event CB and cgeom is not defined (run-time error: cgeom is not defined).Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong there (code is below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Thee.js STL geometry caching test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/STLLoader.js"></script>
    <script>

        alert("We'are here");

        var cgeom;

        function load_geometry( stl_file ) {

            var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();     
            loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
            cgeom = event.content;
                alert('inside listener - vertices: ' + cgeom.vertices.length);
            } );
            loader.load(stl_file);
            alert('inside load_geometry - vertices: ' + cgeom.vertices.length); // error - cgeom is not defined
        }

        load_geometry('./data/a90.stl');     
        alert('inside load_geometry - vertices: ' + cgeom.vertices.length); // error - cgeom is not defined

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

All examples create a mesh from the geometry and add it immediately to the scene. That's not I want. I need to add it later, to replace another mesh in the scene. That's why I'd like to cache it first.

Thank you in advance,
Simon

P.S. I'm not a JS expert, but have 10+ years of c++ and java experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cgeom` will have value only after your event handler has been executed. All your code runs immediately, except this:

```
       loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
           cgeom = event.content;
            alert('inside listener - vertices: ' + cgeom.vertices.length);
        } );
```

So you need to wait for the geometry to load (this callback to run) before you can attempt to use it.

Comment: thanks for the hint. as I said to gaitat, I didn't know that the loading is async. it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add to the scene immediately but you can add it to an external object. So before your loader you can do:

```
var geometriesToLoad = 2;
var geom1 = new THREE.Object3D ();
var geom2 = new THREE.Object3D ();
```

and in the callback you would do:

```
geom.add (cgeom);
geometriesToLoad --;
```

where `geom` is an additional vaiable you pass to your `load_geometry()` routine; either geom1 or geom2.

when `geometriesToLoad` is 0 then all your models have been loaded and you can continue processing. You can check that with a setTimeout call.

Comment: thank you! I didn't realize that loading is asynchronous. I added a check with setTimeout and everything works now!

Answer (score 0):

Thank to gaitat and yaku, the puzzle is solved. The problem was that the loading is done in parallel and I was checking the results before the model was actually loaded. Here is the working code (I'm waiting for model to load in setTimeout callback):

```
<script>

    var cgeom;
    var mt;

    function load_geometry( stl_file ) {

            var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();     
            loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
                cgeom = event.content;
                cgeom.dynamic = true;
                console.log('inside listener - vertices: ' + cgeom.vertices.length);
            } );
            loader.load(stl_file);

    }

    load_geometry('./data/a.stl');     

    // start waiting
    mt = setInterval(function () {
        if (cgeom == undefined )
            console.log('wating ...')
        else {
            console.log('cgeom is defined, loaded vertices: ' + cgeom.vertices.length);
            clearInterval(mt);
        }            
    }, 1000);

    if (cgeom == undefined )
            console.log('cgeom - UNDEFINED ...');

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to this party, but as of three.js R125, the recommended way to do this is with the loadAsync method, which is now native to three.js:

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/Loader.loadAsync

That method returns a promise. You couldthen use a 'then' to get the geometry of the STL and create the mesh. You could also use a traditional callback, or an async/await structure, but I think the example below using the native three.js method is the simplest way. The example shows how you can get geometry to a global variable once the promise is resolved and the STL file is loaded:

```
// Global variables for bounding boxes
let bbox;

const loader = new STLLoader();
const promise = loader.loadAsync('model1.stl');
promise.then(function ( geometry ) {
  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  bbox = mesh.geometry.boundingBox;
  scene.add( mesh );
  buildScene();
  console.log('STL file loaded!');
}).catch(failureCallback);

function failureCallback(){
  console.log('Could not load STL file!');
}

function buildScene() {
  console.log('STL file is loaded, so now build the scene');
  // !VA bounding box of the STL mesh accessible now
  console.log(bbox);
  // Build the rest of your scene...
}
```